# Problem in deleting blank lines in exercise 1-18 (K&R)

Tags: c, arrays, kernighan-and-ritchie

The exercise asks for a program which removes trailing blanks and tabs and also to delete entirely blank lines.
My program deletes blank lines if the input is `\n`, however, I don't understand why doesn't it delete them for input with blanks or tabs before `\n` such as `\t\n`.
Here is the function which "cleans" the input lines and copies them to the output:

```
void clean(char to[], char from[]) 
{
    char storage[MAXLINE];
    int i, c, k;
    i = 0;
    c = 0;

    while (to[i] != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }

    for (k = 0; from[k] != '\0' && i < (MAXCHAR * MAXLINE - 1); ++k) {
        if (from[k] == (' ' || '\t')) {
            storage[c] = from[k];                               //The array storage[] will store me the trailing blanks and tabs
            ++c;
        }
        else if (from[k] == '\n' && to[i] == '\0') {            //If there is a blank line, do not copy into output
            ;
        }
        else {
            storage[c] = '\0';
            for (c = 0; storage[c] != '\0'; ++c) {
                to[i] = storage[c];                             //If there is a character after blanks/tabs, copy storage into output
                ++i;
            }
            to[i] = from[k];                                    //Copy the character
            ++i;
            c = 0;
        }
    }
    to[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `from[k] == (' ' || '\t')` --> `from[k] == ' ' || from[k] == '\t'`

Comment: I didn't try your program, but other than what @kaylum said, everything else seems correct (though it is not a good and maintainable code).

Comment: On page 29, K&R have an example which provides code which does a very similar function to what you are trying to do.  I suggest that you start with that and understand it.  Then modify it to do what you need to do.  I always recommend stepping through code in a debugger.  If you are using visual studio, you can just hit F10 which will step into the first line of your code.  then hit F10 to step line by line, F11 to step into a function, CTRL-F10 to run to where your cursor is.

Comment: The problem is not that it doesn't work, it works as intended except for the fact that the line

Comment: The problem is not that it doesn't work, it works as intended except for the fact that the line       
`else if (from[k] == '\n' && to[i] == '\0') {            //If there is a blank line, do not copy into output
            ;
}`
should not only exclude the lines which only contain a newline character but all the blank lines which do not contain characters apart from `\n \t or ' ' `